# HTML/Javascript if else statement for a HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, if-statement

I'm new to coding, so I apologize that the answer to this is probably obvious. I work in a print shop and I am trying to create a form that will help us when creating estimates, as our pricing depends on square footage and cost of different types of material etc. I was wondering why this else/if statement is not working... I am trying to make it so that if we know the dimensions in feet, the program will tell us the square footage, and that if we only know the dimensions in inches, that it will also tell us the square footage. Not sure what I'm doing wrong... The pieces of the code seem to work individually, but not once they are put together.

(Square feet will calculate no problem. Calculating from inches will not.)

Thanks!

JS:

```
function estimateResults (form) {
  var footWidth = form.footWidth.value;
  var footHeight = form.footHeight.value;
  var inchHeight = form.inchHeight.value;
  var inchWidth = form.inchWidth.value;

if (form.sizeFormat.value = "ft") {
  var decalSize = footWidth * footHeight;
} else {
  var widthConverted = inchWidth / 12;
  var heightConverted = inchHeight / 12;
  var decalSize = widthConverted * heightConverted;

}
   alert ("decal size =" + decalSize);

}
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Decals</title>
</head>

<body>

<form id="decalForm">

<h1> Decal Estimator </h1>

<fieldset>
  <legend> Size: </legend>
  <input type="radio" name="sizeFormat" value="ft" /><label>feet</label><br />
  <input type="radio" name="sizeFormat" value="in" /><label>inches</label><br />


<p><label>Width (in)</label><input type="number" name="inchWidth" /> x <label>Height (in)</label><input type="number" name="inchHeight"/></p>
<p><label>Width (ft)</label><input type="number" name="footWidth" /> x <label>Height (ft)</label><input type="number" name="footHeight"/></p>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<p><label>Quantity:</label>
  <input type="number" name="decalQuantity" /></p>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<p><label>Material:</label>
<select id="materialType" name="material">
  <option value="diecut">Diecut</option>
  <option value="stdVinyl">Standard Vinyl</option>
  <option value="wrapFilm">Wrap Film</option>
  <option value="windowPerf">Window Perf</option>
  <option value="motorsports">Motorsports Vinyl</option>
</select>
</fieldset>


<fieldset>
<p><label>Design:</label>
  <input type="number" name="decalDesignTime" /></p>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<p><label>Install:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="installYN" value="false" /><label>No</label>
  <input type="radio" name="installYN" value="true" /><label>Yes</label><br />

<p><label>Install Time:</label>
  <input type="number" name="decalInstallTime" /></p>
</fieldset>


<fieldset>
  <p><label>Shipping</label>
    <input type="radio" name="shipYN" value="false" /><label>No</label>
    <input type="radio" name="shipYN" value="true" /><label>Yes</label><br />
</fieldset>



  <p><input type="button" value="Estimate" onClick="estimateResults(this.form)"/></p>

</form>

  <p id="decalEstimate"> This is where the answer will go....</p>


<script src="js/estimator.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are missing closing `p` tags in "Material", "Install", and "Shipping".

Answer (score 0):

You are making an assignment:

```
form.sizeFormat.value = "ft"
```

And after that form.sizeFormat.value will have the value "ft" and `if ("ft")` is always true.

If you want to compare it should be:

```
form.sizeFormat.value == "ft"
```